# Application.js doesn't work inside a partial

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, partial

I have a classic scheme - in **application.js** are included all needed JS routines and in the app working fine.

Then I have an AJAX link (remote="true") - after click on this link is called respective partial (lets say **_display_popup.html.haml** - this popup window is opened by **display_popup.js**). This is working fine as well.

Here coming the problem - in this opened popup window are not included the JS routines from **application.js**. I am struggling with this issue whole day, but I still can't find the reason why...

Could anyone, please, give me any advice, in what is the problem and how I could to fix it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/live/

I was having problems with js not working inside my partials loaded with ajax. I just added the .live to attach to elements added after the document is loaded.

```
$('input:radio').click(function () { });  // Doesn't work with partials loaded remotely

$('input:radio').live("click",(function () { }); // works fine
```